# implement github.com/jlaffaye/ftp in golang

Tags: go, ftp

I am new to golang I'm trying to implement an FTP client to get files from a server.
I tried several packages like :"github.com/dutchcoders/goftp" but walk support was not working.
Im currently trying with "github.com/jlaffaye/ftp" but cant seem to connect to the server.

I imported the package and Im simply using the following code to connect:

func main(){

```
ftp,err := Connect(address:port)

ftp.Login("user", "password")
if ftp.Code == 530 {
    log.Println("Failed to Login")
}


log.Println("Successfully Connected to",  ftp)
```

}

when i run it gives undefined: Connect

I am following the godocs for this package

GODOC:    https://godoc.org/github.com/jlaffaye/ftp

Comment: Please provide a reproducable example

Answer (score 2):

You have to precede a function with the package from where this function is.

In your example `Connect` is from `ftp` package, you should write `ftp.Connect` instead.

Do not forget to import the package :

```
import github.com/jlaffaye/ftp
```

at the beginning of the file.